# Inconsistent number of samples in CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a Multinomial Naive Bayes classification on a set of tweets I have.

Here is my code:

```
import codecs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
trainfile = 'train.txt'
testfile = 'test.txt'
word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(codecs.open(trainfile,'r','utf8')) ## Error here
tags = ['Pro_vax','Anti_vax','Neither']
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(trainset, tags)
codecs.open(testfile,'r','utf8')
testset = word_vectorizer.transform(codecs.open(testfile,'r','utf8'))
results = mnb.predict(testset)
print results
```

The file `train.txt` has the following text in it:

```
Vaccines are a very good idea.  They prevent all sorts of deadly diseases.
Vaccines cause autism.  Do not vaccinate your children
Going to read about vaccines.  Then, I am going to see my brother with autism.
```

I've tagged them using the `tags` variable.

The file `test.txt` has the followong text:

```
Do not get your kids vaccinated.  Vaccination and autism are correlated.
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3 9]
```

I'm unfamiliar with the error.  What does it mean, and how can I prevent it from popping up again?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to see if you gave the full traceback, but it looks like tags contains 9 entries, while train only contains three training data points. What does `tags` look like?